# Velocity template doesn't render objects in java spark

Tags: java, velocity, spark-java

So, I am trying to make a page, which fetches data from database and displays it on page.

I am using **Java Spark** for backend with **Velocity template engine**.

I have my records from database put into an array list which stores objects.

```
class DB_record {
    private String id;
    private String value;

    public DB_record(String i, String v){
        this.id = i;
        this.value = v;
    }

    //... getters and setters
}
```

then I have defined this route (it fetches all records of past projects from DB and should display it in my template):

```
get("/projects", (req, res) -> {
    ArrayList<DB_records> db_data = DB.getProjects();

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("db_data", db_data);
    return new VelocityTemplateEngine().render(new ModelAndView(data, "templates/projects.vtl")); //render template
});
```

And here is my template file, which should display all projects:

```
<ul>
    #foreach ($row in $db_data)
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="/projects/$row.getid()" style="font-size:16px"> $row.getvalue() </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    #end
</ul>
```

However, when i acces this page, instead of showing link i.e. to /projects/2 with my value as text for  element, it shows this: /projects/$row.getid() (literally)
It does iterate through list, as proper number of < li > elements is generated, yet the text doesn't render.

I tried editing my db_record class to have public parameters, to have public parameters with getters, private params with getters, yet nothing seems to be working. Whatever I do, it never renders as it should.

I have also tried to put velocity variables in curly braces { }, but it didn't help as well

I am completely lost on what else I could try, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many ways to get that working finally.

My Class:

```
//add public before class  bcos of this not getting the value in my eclipse
public class DB_record implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String value;


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "db_datas{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", value='" + value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Add list :

```
Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<DB_record>db_data = new ArrayList<>();
    DB_record data1 = new DB_record();
    data1.setId("1");
    data1.setValue("soora");

    DB_record data2 = new DB_record();
    data2.setId("2");
    data2.setValue("tamil");
    db_data.add(data1);
    db_data.add(data2);
    dbDataObject.setDbDatas(db_data);
    contextMap.put("db_data",db_data);
```

Finally template:

You have to use property expression only to get the value:

```
<ul>
        #foreach ($row in $db_data)
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="/projects/${row.id}" style="font-size:16px"> ${row.value} </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        #end
    </ul>
```

Comment: 'public' before class was the problem, yes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your only mistake is in the `a href` part. It should have been:

```
<a href="/projects/${row.getid()}" style="font-size:16px"> ${row.getvalue()} </a>
```

Curly brackets around the velocity variable AND its function together.

Comment: I see, well this is a bit annoying. Why does Velocity documentation mention reading properties and methods?

Comment: Sorry dude, I fixed my answer. You just had to put the curly brackets in the right place.

Comment: the other solution fixed the problem - my class was not public (as i had it in file with other classes. Thanks anyway!